# What will be the final release date for KAA 0.10.0

Tags: kaa

Is there any planning to release the KAA  0.10.0 in near feature as i have observed that KAA 0.10.0 is re scheduled to released on 14/Oct/16 as per the [JIRA](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/KAA/?utm_source=kaaproject.org&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=link-kaaproject&selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel)

But still we are in waiting state, So is there any concrete planning to release KAA 0.10.0??

And, If i am not wrong then KAA 0.10.0 release was originally scheduled in the month of the JULY,2016

Comment: Today, I checked on KAA Issue tracker (JIRA) and it shows KAA 0.10.0 released date as Tomorrow (i.e. 28th October, 2016) . i hope this time KAA team never let me down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've already initiated the release process. The deadline is Monday, October 31, 2016.

Sorry for making you wait for too long.